# How much memory do the objects occupy?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I did some tests and was very surprised ... Compilation mode x64. The first test showed 4 bytes, everything is fine here. Second 32. Wow, I thought. And third scoring 32 WTF ???

```
static int count = 10000000;

    static void Array_1()
{
    var size = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
    var arr = new int[count];

    for (var i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        arr[i] = i;
    }

    var mem = GC.GetTotalMemory(true) - size;

    Console.WriteLine("Allocated memory: " + mem + ", per item: " + Math.Truncate((double)mem / count) + ", anti optimize " + arr.Last());
}

static void Array_2()
{
    var size = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
    var arr = new object[count];

    for (var i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        arr[i] = new object();
    }

    var mem = GC.GetTotalMemory(true) - size;

    Console.WriteLine("Allocated memory: " + mem + ", per item: " + Math.Truncate((double)mem / count) + ", anti optimize " + arr.Last().GetHashCode());
}

static void Array_3()
{
    var size = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
    var arr = new C[count];

    for (var i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        arr[i] = new C { Val0 = i, Val1 = i };
    }

    var mem = GC.GetTotalMemory(false) - size;

    Console.WriteLine("Allocated memory: " + mem + ", per item: " + Math.Truncate((double)mem / count) + ", anti optimize " + arr.Last().Val0 + arr.Last().Val1);
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
class C
{
    public int Val0;
    public int Val1;
}
```

My question is not even why in the second test one instance takes 32 bytes. But why in the third test the instance does not take 40 bytes.

Comment: MSDN says _GetTotalMemory = A number that is the best available **approximation** of the number of bytes currently allocated in managed memory._

Comment: You are counting different things. Integers vs  object instances vs classes with and without garbage collection. There's no ambiguity about types and sizes. The problem is in the way you try to measure memory.

Comment: If you want to perform valid memory benchmarks use BenchmarkDotNet. It will show actual memory usage, the number of allocations in each case, object counts per GC generation etc.

Comment: These tests are correct. An experiment with int[] proves the correct result. I also need to know not only the size of the object in memory but also its reference, and other heap infrastructure. Because I can solve the problem in two ways. A native C #. Or pointers plus manual memory management